# How to implement Ransack gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I'm trying to have a search form at the header of every web page that will search through the names of all my "products"

I tried to implement ransack gem, but I am not getting the products filtered results. Through my below code, it just fetches all the products in database and displays. I want to display only searched products.

```
# routes.rb
resources :product do
  collection do
    match 'search' => 'products#search', via: [:get, :post], as: :search
  end
end

# application.controller.rb
before_filter :set_global_search_variable
def set_global_search_variable
  @q = Product.search(params[:q])
  @product_search = @q.result
end

# application.html.erb
<% search_form_for(@q, url: /search, method: :get)  do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

# search_index.erb
<% @product_search.each do |product| %>
  <%= image_tag product.image_url %>
    <%= product.name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

view code

```
= search_form_for @product_searcher || Product.ransack, url: main_app.admin_products_path do |f|
```

controller code

```
def index
  params[:q] ||= { }
  @product_searcher = Product.ransack(params[:q])
  @products = @product_searcher.result
end
```

Comment: thanks @Santhanu , i tried this but iam getting this error   `No Ransack::Search object was provided to search_form_for!`

Comment: @sreena Sorry, I modified the answers. Try that.

Comment: @santhanu it works fine , itz my mistake, the field name i written wrong .it should be name_cont  ,bt i wrote only name. so it didn't worked.... now working fine :) thank you again......

Comment: @santhanu , can you help me t imlement sort price

Comment: Yes, use sort_link helper.

Comment: ```= sort_link [@product_searcher], :name, "Name"```, if name is a product's column, then sort by name will work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84052/discussion-between-sreena-and-santanu).